# Running microsoft access db VBA subroutine using Python

Tags: ms-access, python-3.8

I have a microsoft access db which has a VBA subroutine as follows:

[image]

I am trying the following to run the subroutine:

```
import win32com.client
ac = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
ac.Visible = False
ac.OpenCurrentDatabase(destnDB)
ac.DoCmd.RunMacro('subrt')
ac.Application.Quit()
```

It is a subroutine and not a macro. The access db is grandfathered so I cant change it to macro unless I automate it via Python. I am not sure how to make this work.

Edit:

When using `ac.Run("subrt")` I get the following error:

```
result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146787937), None)
```

Comment: Please edit your question title to something that describes the question you're asking or problem you're having, without simply repeating the information that is already available  in the tags. *Python microsoft access db* is just noise that is already in the tags, so it can be removed entirely.

Comment: Don't use parentheses. See answer.

Comment: If I don't use parenthesis, it gives syntax error when using Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

The routine is VBA not a macro so don't use DoCmd.RunMacro.

Consider:

`ac.Run "subrt"`

If routine has arguments:

`ac.Run "subrt", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"`